# What does '{} \;' mean in the 'find' command context?

Tags: bash, find

I want to delete files, which have `size = 0`. So I tried:

```bsh
find ./ -size 0 | xargs rm
```

But, it has a problem with files in which names begin with space.

Searching on internet I found this:

```bsh
find ./ -size 0 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

It works. However, I think my way using `xargs` is too sophisticated for this.

What does `{} \;` mean?

Could someone explain me?

My English is not very good, so please use simple writing.

Comment: [Empty curly braces and semicolon in bash](http://askubuntu.com/q/711452)

Comment: by the way: There's `-print0` in find and `-0` in xargs. Using them is very much imperative when doing stuff like this. Because if it finds "/ bla"... 

Comment: @DanielB `-print0` and `xargs -0` are both non standard and often useless, `find` alone being able to achieve the same goal without these hacks.

Answer (score 13):

`{}` has absolutely no meaning to `bash`, so is passed unmodified as an argument to the command executed, here `find`.

On the other hand, `;` has a specific meaning to `bash`. It is normally used to separate sequential commands when they are on the same command line. Here the backslash in `\;` is precisely used to prevent the semicolon to be interpreted as a command separator by `bash` and then allow it to be passed as a parameter to the underlying command, `find`. Quoting the semicolon, i.e. `";"` or `';'`, could have been an alternate way to have it stayed unprocessed.

The command:

```
find ./ -size 0 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

means: find in the current directory (note that the `/` is useless here, `.` cannot be but a directory anyway) anything that has a size of 0 and for each object found, run the command `rm -i name`, i.e. interactively prompt for each file if you want to remove it. `{}` is replaced by each file name found in the executed command. One nice feature is that this file name is strictly a single argument, whatever the file name (even containing embedded spaces, tabs, line feeds, and whatever characters). This wouldn't be the case with `xargs`, unless non portable hacks are used. The final `;` is there to end the `-exec` clause. The reason why its end needs to be delimited is that other `find` options might follow the `-exec` one, although it is rarely done. e.g.:

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec ls -l {} \; -name "special*" -exec wc -l {} \;
```

One issue with this command is that it won't ignore non plain files, so might prompt the user to delete sockets, block and character devices, pipes, and directories. It will always fail with the latter even if you answer yes.

Another issue, although not really critical here, is that `rm` will be called for each file that has a zero size. If you substitute the `-exec` ending from `/;` to `+`, `find` will optimize the sub-process creation by only calling `rm` the minimal possible number of times, often just once.

Here is then how I would modify this command:

```
find . -type f -size 0 -exec rm -i {} +
```

Comment: `{}` is [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like It is not. More precisely, parameter substitution requires a `$` character before `{` and requires at least a variable name to be present between the curly braces. `{}` alone has no meaning for the shell and is left unchanged by it.

Comment: Why does this not work without the `+`? What's it doing here?

Comment: @CGTheLegend It doesn't work without the `+` because the `-exec` expression takes a variable number of arguments so needs to be terminated by something to be correctly parsed, and further expressions to be properly found. The terminator can be either `+` or `;`.

Comment: excellent. `The reason why its end needs to be delimited is that other find clauses might follow the -exec one, although it is rarely done.` could you elaborate on this. This will clarify things further down.

Comment: did you mean - exec can be used any number of time on find i.e `find .  -exec ls {} \; -exec echo {} \;`

Comment: @samshers Not only `-exec` but any other clause. I'm going to update my reply to make that clear. Thanks.

Comment: will be gr8 if you can also mention about what kind of other clauses exist

Comment: Okay. What I call *clause* might be just called *option*, *action* or *operand* too. `find` has a complex syntax. It supports regular options followed by one or more paths followed by a list of expressions. These expressions are what I call *clauses*. There are dozens of possible ones (`-name, -prune, -follow, -size, -ok, -delete, -user...`) even more with GNU find.

Comment: @samshers Clause replaced by option in that sentence to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

When using `find -exec`, `{}` is expanded to each result found.

For example, if you have a directory `example` containing 3 files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`, `find example/ -exec rm -i {} \;` will expand to:

```
find example/ -exec rm -i example/a.txt \;
find example/ -exec rm -i example/b.txt \;
find example/ -exec rm -i example/c.txt \;
```

The `\;` at the end is simple an escaped `;` to indicate the end of the exec pattern. Otherwise, it would be interpreted by shell itself.

Comment: The command wouldn't really expand to the three commands you wrote which would result in multiple prompts for the same file and leads to "file not found" errors if you accept to remove them, but simply to: `rm -i "example/a.txt" ; rm -i "example/b.txt" ; rm -i "example/c.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

In conjunction with the `find` command's `exec` option, the `{}` part is replaced by the name of the files found when the command is executed.  The `\;` is important too, because that is what defines the end of the command being executed

For instance

`find ~ -name \*.bak -exec -rm -f {} \;`

would delete all files ending in `.bak` anywhere in the user's home directory or in folders contained inside it.  By executing `rm -f` on each file found.

`xargs` takes standard input lines, usually from a pipe, and forms the tailing part of the  arguments from it when it executed the command you give it

Answer (score 1):

To take each case in turn:-

### `xargs`

What this program does is to add each line from input as a parameter to whatever command is passed as its own parameter , then run the resultant command, so if `find` lists three files `a`, `b` and `c` in the current directory it would give as output:

```
./a
./b
./c
```

If this is piped to `xargs rm`, then this command will be executed:

```
rm ./a ./b ./c
```

However, if `find` also finds a file called `" d e "`, then the executed command becomes:

```
rm ./a ./b ./c ./ d e
```

To handle this, `find` provides an option `-print0`, which adds a null character (`\0`) after each file, instead of the usual new-line. To tell `xargs` that the input is in this form, add the parameter `-0`, so the command:

```
find . ... -print0|xargs -0 rm
```

will build and execute the command:

```
rm "./a" "./b" ."/c" "./ d e "
```

This will work on all file names, including names containing blanks, tabs and new-lines.

### `find -exec`

When this option is called, then what follows (up to `\;`) is executed for each file found. This is not terribly useful unless there is some means to refer to the currently found file and that is what `{}` does. It can be called more than once in the run string, eg to copy a selection of files to a back-up directory:

```
find . ... -exec cp "{}" "/BackUp/{}" \;
```

This in the `find` example above would execute in turn:

```
cp "./a" "/BackUp/./a"
cp "./b" "/BackUp/./b"
cp "./c" "/BackUp/./c"
```

Note that, outside their use in the `find` command, `{` and `}` have special meanings in bash (multiple commands and expanding lists), but they involve other characters between the brackets: the string `{}` is copied literally, so does not need escaping.

Comment: +1, excellent - `find . ... -exec cp "{}" "/BackUp/{}" \;`

Comment: `{ and } have special meanings in bash (multiple commands and expanding lists)` - any examples

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I want to add some more information:

```bsh
find ./ -size 0 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

In the previous command, the `\;` is an escaped semicolon. This prevents the command from being handled by the shell (i.e., normally `;` would separate commands).

The `-exec` argument interprets everything as a command up to that escaped semicolon `\;` (i.e., `rm -i {}` it will be inner command to be executed by `find`).  Within the inner command the `{}` represent the parameter expansion. In pain English, it means "insert the file name found here".

So, if the found files were "file-a.txt" and "file-b.txt", `find` would execute `rm -i file-a.txt` then `rm -i file-b.txt`.

One issue with this command is that it won't ignore non plain files, so might prompt the user to delete sockets, block and character devices, pipes, and directories. It will always fail with the latter even if you answer yes (i.e., directories needs to be deleted recursively)

Another issue, although not really critical here, is that `rm` will be called for each file that has a zero size. If you substitute the `-exec` ending from `/;` to `+`, find will optimize the sub-process creation by only calling `rm` the minimal possible number of times, often just once.

Here is then how I would modify this command:

```bsh
find ./ -type f -size 0 -exec rm -i {} +
```

`curly brackets` or `braces`: `{}` can be used in a different ways

- [Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).
- [Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping)
- [Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
- [Placeholder for text](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=descriptions-xargs-construct-argument-list-run-command)
- [Pathname](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm)

#### Brace expansion

Braces can be used to build sequences:

```bsh
### prints out the numbers from 0 to 10
echo {0..10}

## prints out the same numbers, but in reverse order
echo {10..0}

## prints every second number, from 10 to 0
echo {10..0..2}

## prints every second letter, from z and working its way backwards to a.
echo {z..a..2}
```

Also we can combine two or more sequences:

```bsh
## prints out a pair of letters, from aa to zz.
echo {a..z}{a..z}
```

Adding prefixes and suffixes:

```bsh
### adds '"' as prefix and suffix
echo \"{These,words,are,quoted}\"
# output: "These" "words" "are" "quoted"

# concatenates the files file1, file2, and file3 into combined_file.
cat {file1,file2,file3} > combined_file

# copies "file22.txt" to "file22.backup"
cp file22.{txt,backup}
```

##### Note:

No spaces are allowed within the braces `{...}` unless the spaces are **quoted** or **escaped**.

```bsh
echo {file1,file2}\ :{\ A," B",' C'}
# output: file1 : A file1 : B file1 : C file2 : A file2 : B file2 : C
```

#### Extended Brace expansion.

Braces can be used to build arrays. Arrays in Bash are defined by putting elements between parenthesis `()` and separating each element using a space, like this:

```bsh
month=("Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec")
```

To access an element within the array, you use its index within brackets `[]`:

```bsh
 # Array indexes start at [0], so [3] points to the fourth item
$ echo ${month[3]}
## output: Apr
```

Therefore, we can create an array with something like this:

```bsh
## builds an array that contains all the 2-letter combinations of the entire alphabet.
letter_combos=({a..z}{a..z})

## contains all the binary numbers for an 8-bit register, in ascending order,
## from 00000000, 00000001, 00000010, etc., to 11111111. 
dec2bin=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})
```

This last one is particularly interesting because dec2bin now we can use this to build an 8-bit decimal-to-binary converter. Say you want to know what 25 is in binary. You can do this:

```bsh
$ echo ${dec2bin[25]}
## output: 00011001
```

##### But Teo there are not better ways of converting decimal to binary?

- Yes, there are, but it is still interesting, right?

#### Grouping Commands

`{ ... }` can be used for placing a list of commands to be executed in the current shell context. No [**sub-shell**](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=descriptions-xargs-construct-argument-list-run-command) is created. The semicolon `;` (or newline) following list is **required**.

Parentheses `()` are used to run commands in a **sub-shell**:

```bsh
menu_type=bar
echo $menu_type
## output: bar

## new lets called in a sub-shell
(menu_type=superbar; echo $menu_type)
## output: superbar

## back to the context
echo $menu_type
## output: bar
```

We can not get access to the new value `superbar` of `menu_type`.

However, if we run something like this:

```bsh
{ menu_type=superbar; echo $menu_type; }
## output: superbar

echo $menu_type
## output: superbar
```

`{ ... }` does not create a sub-shell, that is why we can get access to the `menu_type` value.

`{ ... }` are also referred to as an `inline group`, in effect, it creates an anonymous function (i.e., a function without a name). In plain English, unlike in a "standard" function, the variables inside a `{ ... }` remain visible to the remainder of the script.

Also, `{ ... }` can be used to group the output from several commands into `stdout` or to receive a redirection into its `stdin`. Let's see an example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# rpm-check.sh
#  Queries an rpm file for description, listing, and whether it can be installed.
#  Saves output to a file.

SUCCESS=0
E_NOARGS=65

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` rpm-file"
  exit $E_NOARGS
fi  

{ # Begin command group.
  echo
  echo "Archive Description:"
  rpm -qpi $1       # Query description.
  echo
  echo "Archive Listing:"
  rpm -qpl $1       # Query listing.
  echo
  rpm -i --test $1  # Query whether rpm file can be installed.
  if [ "$?" -eq $SUCCESS ]
  then
    echo "$1 can be installed."
  else
    echo "$1 cannot be installed."
  fi  
  echo              # End command group.
} > "$1.test"       # Redirects output of everything in block to file.

echo "Results of rpm test in file $1.test"

exit 0
```

Now, lest see how to proceed with an I/O redirection in the group's `stdin`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
File=/etc/fstab

## reads the first two lines of the file
{
  read line1
  read line2
} < $File

echo "First line in $File is:"
echo "$line1"
echo
echo "Second line in $File is:"
echo "$line2"

exit 0
```

Another example of saving the output of a command group into a file

```bsh
## exec commands sequentially and redirects the output of the ls command into the png-list.txt file
echo "I found all these png files:"; find . -iname "*.png"; echo "Within this bunch of files:"; ls > png-list.txt

## exec commands sequentially and redirects the output of the group into the png-list.txt file
{ echo "I found all these png files:"; find . -iname "*.png"; echo "Within this bunch of files:"; ls; } > png-list.txt
```

##### What is the difference, Teo?

Well, young padawan. The second one creates the file `png-list.txt` with all the outputs, starting with the line `“I found all these png files:“`, and finishing up with the `ls` command output.

#### Sub-shell Hack

Bash makes a sub-shell for a `{ ... }` brace group command **if and only if** it's a part of pipeline, for example:

```bsh
$ { A=1; { A=2; sleep 2; } ; echo $A; }
## output: 2

$ { A=1; { A=2; sleep 2; } | sleep 1; echo $A; }
## output: 1
```

##### Note:

There is space between the braces and the command list enclosed within them. That’s because `{` and `}` are reserved words (i.e., commands built into the shell). Also, the list of commands has to end with a semicolon `;` or use newlines to separate commands.

#### Parameter expansion

Okay, getting back to

```bsh
month=("Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec")
echo ${month[3]}
## output: Apr
```

Here the braces `{}` are not being used as apart of a sequence builder, but as a way of generating parameter expansion. Parameter expansion involves what it says on the box:

> it takes the variable or expression within the braces and expands it to whatever it represents.

##### What this means Teo?

Well, it means `${...}` tells the shell to expand whatever is inside it. In this case, `month` is the array we defined earlier, that is:

```bsh
month=("Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec")
```

And, item `3` within the array points to `"Apr"` (i,e. the first index in an array in Bash is `[0]`). That means that `echo ${month[3]}`, after the expansion, translates to echo `"Apr"`.

Interpreting a variable as its value is one way of expanding it, but there are a few more we can leverage. We can use parameter expansion to manipulate what you read from variable (i.e. by cutting a chunk off the end).

Suppose you have a variable like:

```bsh
a="This sentence is too longgg"

## chops off the last two gs
echo ${a%gg}
## output: This sentence is too long
```

This can be useful for converting files from one format to another. For example, if we have a command that takes a JPEG image called `image.jpg` and converts into a PNG image called `image.png`:

```bsh
convert image.jpg image.png
```

We can rewrite it like this:

```bsh
i='image.jpg'
## chops off the extension 'jpg' and adds 'png'
convert $i "${i%jpg}png"
## output: convert image.jpg image.png
```

##### But teo how can be this more useful than just writing in the name of the file?

Well, when we have a directory containing hundreds of JPEG images, you need to convert to PNG, just run the following in it:

```bsh
for i in *.jpg; do convert $i ${i%jpg}png; done
```

… and all the pictures get converted automatically. Your welcome young padawan.

If you need to chop off a chunk from the beginning of a variable, instead of `%`, use `#`:

```bsh
$ a="Hello World!"

## chops off the word 'Hello' and adds 'Goodbye'
$ echo Goodbye${a#Hello}
## output: Goodbye World!
```

#### Placeholder for text

Used after `xargs -i` (i.e., replace strings option). The `{}` double curly brackets are a placeholder for output text.

```bsh
## Execute 'echo ./<file>' for each file in the directory
ls . | xargs -i -t echo ./{} $1
#            ^^         ^^
```

#### Pathname

A pathname is a filename that includes the complete path. As an example, `/home/<user>/Notes/todo.txt`. This is sometimes referred to as the absolute path.
We will encounter `{}` mostly in `find` constructs that contains `-exec <command> \;`. However, this is not a shell builtin.
If `<command>` contains `{}`, then find substitutes the full path name of the selected file for `"{}"`.

```bsh
# Removes all core dump files from user's home directory.
find ~/ -name 'core*' -exec rm {} \;
```